# how to solve Android Place Autocomplete intent issue?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-mapview, placeautocompletefragment

I'm trying to use google [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/autocomplete) in my app.

Like described in the documentation, there is two ways to use this feature : one using a fragment and the other way is to use an Intent and that's what I choose.

My code is like below

***Gradle:***

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.5.0'
```

***Kotlin:***

Part 1

```
 btn.setOnClickListener {

            if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
                Places.initialize(
                    requireActivity().applicationContext,
                    getString(R.string.google_maps_key)
                )
            }

            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            startActivityForResult(
                Autocomplete
                    .IntentBuilder(
                        AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY,
                        listOf(
                            Place.Field.ID,
                            Place.Field.NAME,
                            Place.Field.LAT_LNG,
                            Place.Field.ADDRESS,
                            Place.Field.ADDRESS_COMPONENTS
                        )
                    ).build(requireContext()),
                AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE
            )
        }
```

Part 2

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            when (resultCode) {
                Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                    data?.let {
                        val place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data)
                        Timber.i(TAG, "Place: ${place.name}, ${place.id}")
                    }
                }
                AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR -> {
                    // TODO: Handle the error.
                    data?.let {
                        val status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data)
                        Timber.i(TAG, status.statusMessage)
                    }
                }
                Activity.RESULT_CANCELED -> {
                    // The user canceled the operation.
                }
            }
            return
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
```

The overlay 'Place Auto Complete' view appear perfectly but when I try to tape in the keyboard to search for some place, the view crashes not the app. only the view and I got the error below (I don't know if it is related) :

```
set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you "enable" your api key for using the google places?

Comment: Instead of posting as answer, please use comments section under the question to clarify any queries related to question .

Comment: @Christos I did but I got the same issue !

Comment: You also must add a credit card account,to your google console,because after a number of request there is a charge.